# Confusion over basis sets in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

In a sense, I feel like I understand every step in the following (fairly typical) calculation, but I don't understand the conclusion.

I consider a vector space spanned by two basis vectors $|\phi_A\rangle$ and $|\phi_B\rangle$. I can use this basis to decompose an arbitrary state:

$$
|\psi\rangle=\sum_{i=A,B}\langle\phi_i|\psi\rangle|\phi_i\rangle=\sum_{i=A,B}\phi_i|\phi_i\rangle,
$$

where I have defined $\phi_i=\langle\phi_i|\psi\rangle$.

Now I assume that $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenvector of the Hamiltonian, so that (invoking the resolution of the identity in the first step):

$$
\langle\phi_m|H|\psi\rangle=\sum_{i=A,B}\langle\phi_m|H|\phi_i\rangle\langle\phi_i|\psi\rangle=\sum_{i=A,B}H_{m,i}\phi_i=E\langle\phi_m|\psi\rangle=E\phi_m
$$

where I have defined $H_{m,i}=\langle\phi_m|H|\phi_i\rangle$.

Equating terms we see that  $\sum_{i=A,B}H_{m,i}\phi_i=E\phi_m$, which reminds us of the rule for matrix multiplication. Therefore, we represent the operator $H$ by a matrix acting on a vector which represents the state $|\psi\rangle$:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
H_{A,A} & H_{A,B}\\
H_{B,A} & H_{B,B}
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\phi_{A}\\
\phi_{B}
\end{matrix}
\right]=E\left[
\begin{matrix}
\phi_{A}\\
\phi_{B}
\end{matrix}
\right].
$$

The column vector could instead be written:

$$
|\psi\rangle=\left[\begin{matrix}
\phi_{A}\\
\phi_{B}
\end{matrix}
\right]=\phi_A\left[\begin{matrix}
1\\
0
\end{matrix}
\right]+\phi_B\left[\begin{matrix}
0\\
1
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$.

But hang on, that expansion is exactly the same as the expansion I made in the very first equation, if we make the identification:

$$
|\phi_A\rangle=\left[\begin{matrix}
1\\
0
\end{matrix}
\right];|\phi_B\rangle=\left[\begin{matrix}
0\\
1
\end{matrix}
\right].
$$

I don't understand this: I thought the basis I chose in the beginning was arbitrary, but now I seem to know what my basis vectors are. That is, they are not arbitrary at all, and I at least think I know what they are specifically.

My feeling is that I have at some point (without realizing) assumed that this is my basis. I think this was likely the step in which I assumed that $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $H$. Is that correct?

Comment: in the first part:$|\psi\rangle=\sum_{i=A,B}|\phi_{i}\rangle\langle 
\phi_{i}|\psi\rangle$ is the state of your system, which is written as a linear combination of the energy eigenvectors $|\phi_{i}\rangle$.i.e, If you operate with the Hamiltonian, the system will go to one of the eigenstates $|\phi_{i}\rangle$ and gives the eigenvalue $E_{i}$, and the probability for that is given by the coefficient $|\langle 
\phi_{i}|\psi\rangle|^{2}$.

Comment: Hint: in writing the wave vector as $[\phi_A,\phi_B]^T$, what have you assumed your basis to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My feeling is that I have at some point (without realizing) assumed that this is my basis. I think this was likely the step in which I assumed that $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $H$. Is that correct?

That was not the step where this happened. There were two crucial steps: in the first you invoked "resolution of the identity" which implicitly assumes $\langle\phi_a|\phi_b\rangle = \delta_{ab},$ so the vectors became orthogonal and of unit size, precisely the sort of vectors which could be a basis for a 2D vector space.

The step where this then more directly happened was when you decided that you would define:$$H_{ab} = \langle\phi_a|\hat H|\phi_b\rangle, ~~\psi_a = \langle \phi_a|\psi\rangle.$$

At this very point you decided that if $|\psi\rangle$ were $|\phi_0\rangle$ then you were going to assign it coordinates $\psi_0 = 1, \psi_1 = 0,$ thus being the $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ element of the vector space in that basis.

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand the manipulations you made, you should first of all understand that the column vector notation is a relative one, in the sense that it is defined with respect to some (arbitrary) fixed basis (at least in the context of formal vector spaces). Every finite-dimensional vector space admits a basis; so you can always decompose one of its elements in terms of that basis:

$$
x=\sum_{i}\ c_{i}\ e_{i}\qquad \qquad y=\sum_{i}\ d_{i}\ e_{i}
$$
and so on, where the $e_{i}$'s are the elements that make up the basis. As for the sum of $x$ and $y$, you can set

$$
x+y=\sum_{i}(c_{i}+d_{i})\ e_{i}
$$
This sum has precisely the same algebraic properties as the sum defined between two column vectors: if you define $x$ and $y$ to be
$$
x=\begin{pmatrix}c_{1}\\\vdots\\c_{n}\end{pmatrix}\qquad\qquad y=\begin{pmatrix}d_{1}\\\vdots\\d_{n}\end{pmatrix}
$$
then
$$
x+y=\begin{pmatrix}c_{1}+d_{1}\\\vdots\\c_{n}+d_{n}\end{pmatrix}
$$
This algebraic property does not depend upon the basis you chose. On the other hand, the coefficients $c_{i}$ and $d_{i}$ do. Let's say, however, that you have fixed a basis. Then the column vector representation for the elements of that basis is
$$
e_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}\qquad\qquad e_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}\qquad \qquad\dots\qquad\qquad e_{n}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$
The elements of other bases can be expressed in this representation too. As we have
$$
e_{j}'=\sum_{i}\ b_{ji}\ e_{i}
$$
for some set of coefficients $b_{ji}$ (here $\{e_{j}'\}$ is the second basis), then in the representation you chose
$$
e'_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}b_{11}\\b_{12}\\\vdots\\b_{1n}\end{pmatrix}\qquad\qquad e'_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}b_{21}\\b_{22}\\\vdots\\b_{2n}\end{pmatrix}\qquad \qquad\dots\qquad\qquad e'_{n}=\begin{pmatrix}b_{n1}\\b_{n2}\\\vdots\\b_{nn}\end{pmatrix}
$$
In conclusion, the column vector representation is always given in relation to some specific basis; the elements of the basis through which you decided to represent the elements of the vector space (and only them) then must be represented by column vectors with one $1$ and $n-1$ $0$'s in their rows. What you ask in your question does not depend on QM or on the Hamiltonian; its answer is a general fact of (elementary) representation theory in linear algebra.